# How to destroy unity objects created in an static class?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please consider the following code. It creates a material and shader from a certain path. It's a utility to use in an editor extensions.

```
public static class GpuImageProcessing
{
    private static readonly string matPath = Application.dataPath + "/Uplus/Zcommon/Material/ImageProcessing/";

    private static Shader Gaussian2D5Shader;
    private static Material Gaussian2D5Mat;
    static GpuImageProcessing()
    {
        Gaussian2D5Shader = (Shader) AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(matPath 
           + "Gaussian2D5.shader", typeof(Shader));
        Gaussian2D5Mat = new Material(Gaussian2D5Shader);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is how can I destroy this material before editor recompiles each time some script is changed? I mean after some code is changed the editor needs to recompile scripts and create a new execution context and a new version of this `GpuImageProcessing` will be created. I want to destroy the materials created in previous runtime.

**PS:** This is included in a DLL file so I can't make it a `ScriptableObject` and listen to the event callbacks and also because it's a utility class I really like it being static.

Comment: The class does *not* have to be static. You can just make the functions inside it static.....

Comment: @Programmer Good point. But even if it's a ScriptableObject, Still can't listen to the unity lifecycle events, right? Since there is no GameObject in the scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Programmer Figured out a workaround to ensure the destruction of materials. In order for this to work, the class should become a singleton and inherit from `ScriptableObject`. Then we can implement OnDisable() and it will be called when editor is recompiling. Here is the working example:

```
public class GpuImageProcessing:ScriptableObject
{
    private static readonly string matPath = "Assets/Uplus/Zcommon/Material/ImageProcessing/";

    private Material Gaussian2D5Mat;
    private Material Gaussian1DVariableMat;

    private static GpuImageProcessing _instance;
    private bool destroyedAlready;

    public static GpuImageProcessing Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance != null) return _instance;
            _instance= CreateInstance<GpuImageProcessing>();
            _instance.Init();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        var Gaussian2D5Shader = (Shader)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(matPath + "Gaussian2D5.shader", typeof(Shader));
        Gaussian2D5Mat = new Material(Gaussian2D5Shader);

        var gaus1dVarShader = (Shader)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(matPath + "Gaussian1DVariable.shader", typeof(Shader));
        Gaussian1DVariableMat = new Material(gaus1dVarShader);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log("On disable GpuImgProc");
        if(destroyedAlready) return;
        DestroyImmediate(Gaussian2D5Mat);
        DestroyImmediate(Gaussian1DVariableMat);
        destroyedAlready = true;
        DestroyImmediate(this);
    }
}
```

**Important:** Please notice the destroyedAlready field. It ensures materials are destroyed only once since the OnDisable is called two times (one when unity editor invokes it and one when we `DestroyImmediate(this)`). Please set `destroyedAlready` before calling `DestroyImmediate(this)`.

While not the exact solution for original question and not a nice solution, it does work and prevents the memory leak while preserving the static nature of the class.